# How to custom Uber API map?

Tags: javascript, uber-api

After you start a ride with Uber API you get a ride object including Uber map url. I load this url to an iframe and introduce it in my app.

I want to change some details in Uber map while ride is live:

1. How do I change the upper title "LIAT IS EN ROUTE" or remove it at
   all?
2. Is there any way to remove the Uber app banner at the bottom?

[image: see printscreen of the map attached]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code, please ?

Comment: It is not possible to customize the map today.

Answer (score 0):

This map cannot be customized. It's an HTML page with static overlay.